Why do I lose all video when I add a GPU to my PC?
When I add a Quadro p1000 to my Lenovo p330 I lose all video. Neither the card or integrated video output anything.
If I remove the GPU the integrated video behaves as expected.
With the GPU removed and the machine behaving normally, I download the nvidia mgmt app and drivers. I ran the setup and it exited because I didn't have a GPU installed.
In the BIOS I have selected the PCI express option for video assuming that would prioritize the pci card over the onboard graphics.
What am I missing?

A quadro p1ooo? Shouldn't that be a quadro p1000? :-)

Its possible the GPU is a DOA (dead on arrival). Its also possible the GPU needs additional power. Does the BIOS even post or give a status code somewhere?

@Dominique - yes it should - edited!

@LPChip - I reinstalled the OS, the card was in the machine when I got it and the on board display ports were working. Now the onboard display ports are not working with the clean install and the card installed.
What's confusing is the fact that when I put the card in, the on board display ports don't work, If I pull the card out the onboard display works fine. I'll try safe mode and see if I can get the drivers added with the card physically installed.
